# How to solve this equation

Tags: mathematics

$$ {2\over x-14}+ {5\over x-11} = {5\over x-13}+ {2\over x-9}$$

It is puzzling me for a days. I'm getting huge polynomial I don't like.

Comment: This is a math problem, not a math puzzle - the distinction is that a math puzzle has some sort of trick that isn't necessarily covered by just throwing math at them. If you want an example, most of [Mind Your Decisions](https://www.youtube.com/user/MindYourDecisions/featured)' videos are about math puzzles, which involve some sort of clever thinking, an unexpected application of a proof, etc. that bumps it from a problem to a puzzle

Comment: Well, this is one of those you are describing. @samm82

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write with a common denominator and you will get
$$\frac{x-17}{(x-9)(x-11)(x-13)(x-14)}=0,$$
which has solution $x=17$.

Comment: How you came up with that. Some steps please.

Comment: @Greedoid Combine the two fractions with the numerator 2, and combine the two fractions with numerator 5. The two fractions you get will have simple numerators. Then combine those two fractions.

Comment: Would you say that is classical aproach or creative one @JaapScherphuis

Comment: @Greedoid I'd call it an obvious one. By combining the ones with the same numerator, the x-terms disappear.

Comment: I don't know if it is obviously, it is from contest for 8. graders.

Comment: @Greedoid (a) Then it's unattributed, which is another reason puzzles get closed and (b) was it from a math contest or a puzzle contest?

Comment: Is there a puzzle contest? @samm82

Comment: @Greedoid There are many, two quick examples being the [College Puzzle Challenge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/College_Puzzle_Challenge) and the [MIT Mystery Hunt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIT_Mystery_Hunt). From your answer, I think I can assume that this was from a math contest, and since the answer comes from doing simple math with no clever trick or surprising way of thinking to solve it, required for it to be considered a puzzle, it's clear that this belongs on Math SE.